# Installing Pycharm in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install pycharm through Ubuntu Terminal and after I unpack the tar.gz I'm not sure what to do after that.

Are there any instructions for this?

Answer (score 36):

First, you need to make sure you have Oracle java installed. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk) on how to do that.

Then, just run the `pycharm` executable from the expanded archive. It will be in the `bin` directory.

Comment: To install you should type `./pycharm.sh` when in `bin` directory. Note that `./` is important.